# ScrollY is not working with overflow:auto

Tags: css, web, scroll, web-deployment, css3pie

I'm using `overflow:auto` is my code and scrollY is not working with it. Can I use scrollY with `overflow:auto` simultaneously? Because I do want my parent `div` to cover all overflowing blocks, besides I also want to control `scrollY`. Is there a way that I use both `scrollY` and `overflow:auto` together? Following is the CSS of my parent `div`:

```
#react-root {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```